# writing byte array to a raw column in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, arrays, prepared-statement

I want to write a byte array to a raw column in oracle.

```
byte[] bArray = new byte[16];
stmt = fConnection.prepareStatement(query);
```

I want to do something like:

```
stmt.setBinaryStream(1, bArray );
```

However, I couldn't figure out an elegant way of doing it. Can some one please throw in some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There the [`setBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBytes%28int,%20byte%5B%5D%29) method is for.

```
stmt.setBytes(1, bArray);
```

Click the above `setBytes()` link for an overview of all methods of the `PreparedStatement` class. It's called *javadoc*. Start familarizing you with the javadocs. They are invaluable.